# Aptana Studio 3 shows many errors in the console at start

Tags: windows, bundle, aptana

(at 1-st sorry for some eng. grammar mistakes ;p)

My Aptana 3 starts with many errors in console. I don't know, that they are making any problems, but i won't have problems in the fiture.. There is a content from console:

```
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] Attempted to define a bundle in a file other than the bundle's bundle.rb file: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\bundle.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] Attempted to define a bundle in a file other than the bundle's bundle.rb file: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\bundle.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Clean Up Old Releases: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\commands\clean_up_old_releases.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Show Active Commands in Scope: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\commands\active_scope_commands.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Show Active Snippets in Scope: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\commands\active_scope_snippets.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Deploy: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\commands\deploy.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Deploy With Migrations: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\commands\deploy_with_migrations.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Disable Application: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\commands\disable_application.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Display Pending Commits: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\commands\display_pending_commits.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Show Command Bindings: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\commands\command_bindings.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Copy Scope: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\commands\copy_scope.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Display Pending Diffs: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\commands\display_pending_diffs.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Enable Application: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\commands\enable_application.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Migrate Database: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\commands\migrate_database.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Show ENV: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\commands\env.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:15] No bundle found for command Flush Bundle Caches: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\commands\flush_cache.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Install Bundle: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\commands\install_bundle.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Open Capistrano Documentation: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\commands\open_capistrano_documentation.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Restart App Servers: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\commands\restart_app_servers.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Rollback: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\commands\rollback.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Start App Servers: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\commands\start_app_servers.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Show Scope: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\commands\show_scope.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Show Scope and Matching Theme Rule: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\commands\show_theme.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Stop App Servers: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\capistrano.ruble\commands\stop_app_servers.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] Attempted to define a bundle in a file other than the bundle's bundle.rb file: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\css.ruble\bundle.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for env Ruble::Env: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\css.ruble\bundle.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for smart_typing_pairs Ruble::SmartTypingPairs: C:\Users\Krystuś\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\css.ruble\bundle.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Documentation for Property: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\css.ruble\commands\docs_for_property.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Update User Bundles: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\commands\update.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Validate Snippets: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\commands\validate_snippets.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Format CSS Single-line: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\css.ruble\commands\format_css_singleline.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Insert Color...: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\css.ruble\commands\insert_color.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Preview: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\css.ruble\commands\preview.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] Attempted to define a bundle in a file other than the bundle's bundle.rb file: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\snippets\snippets.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for project template Ruble Template: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\bundle-development.ruble\templates\template.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Validate Selected CSS: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\css.ruble\commands\validate_selected_css.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] Attempted to define a bundle in a file other than the bundle's bundle.rb file: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\css.ruble\snippets\snippets.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] Attempted to define a bundle in a file other than the bundle's bundle.rb file: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\coffeescript.ruble\bundle.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for env Ruble::Env: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\coffeescript.ruble\bundle.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for smart_typing_pairs Ruble::SmartTypingPairs: C:\Users\Krystuś\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\coffeescript.ruble\bundle.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for template CSS Template: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\css.ruble\templates\templates.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Align Assignments: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\coffeescript.ruble\commands\align_assignments.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Compile and Display JS: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\coffeescript.ruble\commands\compile_and_display_js.rb
[2012-11-03 22:30:16] No bundle found for command Insert Heredoc """ comment: C:\Users\Krystu�\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\91\1\.cp\bundles\coffeescript.ruble\commands\insert_heredoc_comment.rb
...and more more more...
```

I'm thinking, that could be because of user name in win with "Ś" sign, and aptana can't work with it.. But can i change it in any options? I didn't find it, and i won't change account name because of many other apps.. ;/

Thank you for any advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use special chars in your username.

"Krystu�" that ? sign indicates there is a problem with your username.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** execute Aptana Studio 3 with the option **Run as administrator**.

I had the same problem under Windows 8.1. My user name is `Iván`, but I found that the issue was not the name. If you run the application as administrator you will have no problems.

Also, I tried [Changing the User Bundle Directory](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Changing+the+User+Bundle+Directory) with no luck.